# Where is hash to curve used?

Tags: hash, elliptic-curves

I'm curious to hear of algorithms that use this new standard (there is a new [IRTF CFRG Draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-hash-to-curve) for it, for instance). It's useful for verifiably deterministic signatures on elliptic curves, but what else?

Comment: @kodlu: in the CFRG, it's known as the 'Hash2Curve' draft.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen it referenced in the [Verifiable Random Functions](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-vrf) draft, and referenced by projects implementing [BLS Signatures](https://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2001/22480516.pdf). Hash-to-curve more generally is also used in [linkable ring signatures](https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/027.pdf) to provide the 'key image' / 'tag' that can be used to check if a ring signature has been anonymously produced by the same person twice.